# invisible lowercase 'o's in textarea

Tags: css, textarea, font-awesome

For whatever reason, lowercase 'o's are invisible in my textarea. Every other letter works fine. If I highlight it, its still invisible.

```
 ______________             ______________ 
|              |           |              |
| hello world! | shows as  | hell  w rld! |
|______________|           |______________|
```

When I actually post the form, or copy and paste from it, the 'o's are indeed there.

I'm just going to list everything that contributes to this textarea, and hopefully you guys can suggest what might be going wrong. I'm baffled.

- Both Firefox and Chrome
- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms)
- [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/)
- Automatically resizing textarea [following this tutorial](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/expanding-text-areas-made-elegant/)
- The styling below (its [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/))

Border-radius and box-sizing do the expected, and are used throughout the site without issue.

```
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px; // this is overwritten with javascript
  color: white;
  text-shadow: black 0.05em 0.05em 0.08em;
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  @include border-radius(0); // to override bootstrap
  @include box-sizing;
  resize: none;

  &:focus {
    background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.2);
  }
}
```

I just want to reiterate, *every other character on my keyboard shows up fine*. What could possibly be causing these problem-'o's (sorry)

Comment: Have you tried another font?

Comment: please reproduce the issue in a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: For gosh sakes, try another font.  At least disable "font awesome" and see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This only effecting lower case 'o' would point to this being an issue with that specific glyph in the font that is being used to render the text in the textarea. Have you tried using a different font face?

See:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/417

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jurgemaister. Sure enough, switching to `font-family arial;` worked. For some reason Font Awesome did not get along with the textarea.

Comment: Nice to know that helped. When troubleshooting and you have several external resources, always try to exclude them one by one to see if any of them causes the problem. I often find external libraries to cause trouble, especially when being combined.